# Incremental addition of column components in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I get the following output in Oracle 11g ?

```
Subjects      Marks     add_marks      %marks
Maths 1        68      
Maths 2        50         118           45.73
Maths 3        60         178           68.99
Maths 4        80         258           100.00
-----------------------------------------------
Total          258
```

I am not able to code for the add_marks column particularly. Its incremental nature is complicating the things.

Comment: not clear at all, what do you want to do, what do you want to addition to what?

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO The OP is looking for a cumulative sum of the `marks` column.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `SUM( ... ) OVER ( ORDER BY ... )` analytic function:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dcf00/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Subjects, Marks ) AS
SELECT 'Maths 1', 68 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Maths 2', 50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Maths 3', 60 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Maths 4', 80 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT subjects,
       marks,
       SUM( marks ) OVER ( ORDER BY subjects ) AS add_marks,
       100 * SUM( marks ) OVER ( ORDER BY subjects ) / SUM ( MARKS ) OVER () AS "%marks"
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dcf00/2/0)**:

```
| SUBJECTS | MARKS | ADD_MARKS |             %marks |
|----------|-------|-----------|--------------------|
|  Maths 1 |    68 |        68 | 26.356589147286822 |
|  Maths 2 |    50 |       118 | 45.736434108527135 |
|  Maths 3 |    60 |       178 |   68.9922480620155 |
|  Maths 4 |    80 |       258 |                100 |
```